# Rewrite Rule не работает

Tags: php, .htaccess

Столкнулся с проблемой. Хочу заменить урл  **/?do=upload** на **/upload**. Испульзую такую конструкцию:

```
if ($_GET['do'] == 'upload') {

    echo "upload page";

}

RewriteRule ^upload$ ?do=upload
```

Но  она не работает, если перейти по адресу **/upload**. Но при этом работает следующее:

```
if ($_GET['user']) {

    echo $_GET['user'];

}

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ ?user=$1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть  проблема? И как  мне  вывести **upload page** перейдя по адресу **/upload**.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^login login.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ ?user=$1
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)$ ?id=$1

RewriteRule ^upload ?do=upload
```

Comment: Покажите всю конструкцию обработки урл

Comment: @Walfler  пожалуйста - https://pastebin.com/p3esAGg7

Comment: обратите внимание, что `^upload` ваш вполне себе входит в маску `^([a-z0-9]+)`. более специфичные маски должны идти раньше

Comment: @teran реально. Поставил выше - заработало. Спасибо :3